# SharePoint App Model - 500 Server Error loading JS from SharePoint

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

We are trying to get up and running with SharePoint App Model development. However, we are running into a problem.

Firstly, let me state that we have a DNS entry that routes all sundomains in the form of:
*.ourdevserver.ourappdomain.net to the IP of our devserver.

When our app loads, it runs out and attempts to load three js files from SharePoint.  Those requests look like this:

MS Ajax:
http:// apps-13c02829da8acd.ourdevserver.ourappdomain.net/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js

sp.runtime.js:
http:// apps-13c02829da8acd.ourdevserver.ourappdomain.net/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js

and finally sp.js:
http:// apps-13c02829da8acd.ourdevserver.ourappdomain.net/_layouts/15/sp.js

The GET for each of these files fails with a 500 server error (not a DNS error). This, in turn, prevents the app from working correctly.  The code that loads these files is the default code that is created when you start a new SP app project in Visual Studio:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

Now, I can change the script reference to dispense with the app-xxxxx subdomain and it will work just fine pulling the three files from ourdevserver.ourappdomain.net/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js. So, it feels like this is an issue with IIS being able to handle the request.

Any ideas?

Comment: It turns out that I was able to alter the path to the JS files by prepending ..  This loads the files from the virtual folders on each site.  In lieu of a better answer.  I am going with that.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

It work for me, becasue your app want get parent side's js files which not allowed.